# JAVA API Wrapper for TWAIN Driver

Tags: java, twain

I have an Image Capture project where:

1. I want to be able to identify scanners on the network so that it can be selected as a datasource for input.
2. I want to be able to control the scanner, capturing the image using the TWAIN driver.
3. The project is in JAVA so would like a JAVA wrapper or API for the TWAIN driver and/or TWAIN DSM.

In researching, I was first trying to find open source code for TWAIN, but this seems to dead-end on JAVA.
I can find commercial software such as from Aprise and Morena, but both seems not up-to-date.  JTWAIN seems to be the most popular but seems dated.  Open Source seems to be in worse shape where last activity is years ago:

- http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/plugins/twain-scan.html
- http://www.coderanch.com/t/273864/java/java/Scanner-Twain-Java
- [Acquire Images in java using TWAIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664390/acquire-images-in-java-using-twain)

Is there any support, stable Java TWAIN wrappers?
Are there any commercial solutions other than JTWAIN, Morena or EZTWAIN?

I am not looking for SANE driver and wrapper as I have found something already if we went down the SANE path.

Thanks,

Jason

Answer (score 1):

The first comment I have is that if you're developing something to run in a web browser steer clear of Java.

That being said, if this is an application instead of an applet intended for web, I've had great success with Morena.  As for Morena, Aprise, and JTwain, don't get too excited over lack of updates.  TWAIN, being a 23-year-old scanner specification, has reached a maturity where it hasn't and won't change much.  The TWAIN developers have now focused on a new standard called TWAIN Direct, which is to eventually supersede TWAIN itself through driverless network scanning.

If you want a browser-based scanning solution use Dynamsoft.  They have a plugin for everything.  If you need a browser-based solution and that's not an affordable option you'll have to write custom browser plugins.

Hopefully we can look forward to this being implemented on other OSes:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/documentScan

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can try Dynamic .NET TWAIN. Although Dynamsoft does not directly provide a Java TWAIN solution, they keep .NET version up-to-date, supporting x86 and x64. You can easily wrap DOTNET APIs by reading the article - [Java TWAIN with Dynamic .NET TWAIN and jni4net](http://www.codepool.biz/java-twain-with-dynamic-net-twain-and-jni4net.html).
Here is the source code: https://github.com/Dynamsoft/JavaTwain

Answer (score 0):

You can try my TWAIN JAVA API. 
But one problem which I did not solve yet, is the Windows-x86_64 drivers. 
The sample twain driver works perfectly on java x86 and x64.
But some drivers like HP or Kyrocera only work on x86 java.

[Twain Java Library](https://github.com/DenisLAD/twain4java)